# Models for Eilenberg-MacLane space K(Z,3)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, hilbert-spaces, fibre-bundles

Denote by $U(H)$ and $PU(H)$ the unitary and projective unitary groups on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$. Recall that $U(H)$ is contractible by Kuiper's theorem and that $PU(H)$ is a $K(Z,2)$.

In Section 6 of

- Alan L. Carey, Diarmuid Crowley, Michael K. Murray, *Principal Bundles and the Dixmier Douady Class*, Commun. Math. Phys. **193** (1998) pp 171–196, doi:[10.1007/s002200050323](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002200050323), [arXiv:hep-th/9702147](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9702147)

it was shown that there is a principal $PU(H)$-bundle
\begin{equation}
PU(H) \rightarrow U(T) \rightarrow U(T)/PU(H)
\end{equation}
where $T$ is the Hilbert space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators on $H$. This comes from the closed embedding of Banach Lie groups
\begin{eqnarray}
i: PU(H) &\rightarrow& U(T) \\
[a] &\mapsto& Ad(a)
\end{eqnarray}
where $Ad(a)$ sends $t\in T$ to $ata^*$. It follows that $U(T)/PU(H)$ is a $K(Z,3)$.

I'm interested the possible generalization to general linear groups. We can consider the map
\begin{eqnarray}
i: PGL(H) &\rightarrow& GL(T) \\
[a] &\mapsto& Ad(a)
\end{eqnarray}
where $Ad(a)$ sends $t\in T$ to $ata^{-1}$. I tried to imitate the proof in the paper and had to prove the following:

1. $i$ is well-defined
2. $i$ is injective
3. $i$ is continuous
4. $i(PGL(H))$ is closed
5. $i$ is a homeomorphism onto its image

I was able to prove 1)-3) so far.

My questions:

> Are statements 4) and 5) above true?

> Regardless, do we anyway have a fiber bundle $PGL(H) \rightarrow GL(T) \rightarrow GL(T)/PGL(H)$?

> In any case, is $GL(T)/PGL(H)$ a model for $K(Z,3)$?

Comment: ($U(H)$,norm topology) is contractible by Kuiper's theorem. But the norm topology sucks. ($U(H)$,strong operator topology) is a much better group to work with. See the review paper _[The Unitary Group In Its Strong Topology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5891)_ for more info. ($U(H)$,strong operator topology) is also contractible, and the proof is much, much simpler than Kuiper's theorem. Here's the proof: write $H$ as $L^2([0,1])$, and use the nullhomotopy $u\mapsto \{u_t\}$, where $u_t$ acts like $u$ on $L^2([t,1])$, and acts like $id$ on $L^2([0,t])$.

Comment: Just in case anybody stumbles across this question while searching for models of $K(\mathbb Z, 3)$ more generally (which seems likely given the title), let me link to [this old gem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44045/naturally-occuring-k-pi-n-spaces-for-n-geq-2/46634).

Comment: @AndréHenriques one problem is, it's not clear if $U(H)$ with the strong operator topology (=weak operator topology=compact-open topology, in this case) is a Lie group (it's not a Lie group, as noted at your reference, modeled on the bounded skew-symmetric operators)