# Geometric models for 2-gerbes

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gerbes

One can think of a complex line bundle as a geometric model for an integral cohomology class of degree 2. Similarly, a locally-trivial bundle of $C^*$-algebras with fiber B(H) (the $C^*$-algebra of bounded operators on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space) can be thought of as a geometric model for an integral cohomology class of degree 3. One can say that such a bundle is a 1-gerbe, while a complex line bundle is a 0-gerbe. Are there similarly nice models for integral cohomology classes of degree 4 (that is, for 2-gerbes)?

Comment: $E_8$ principal bundles? :)

Comment: One silly answer is: your description of 0 and 1 gerbes is equivalent to the observation that $K(\mathbb{Z},2)=BU(1)$ and $K(\mathbb{Z},3)=BPU(H)$. So we want to identify $K(\mathbb{Z},4)$ as $BG$ for some topological group $G$. But of course we could take $G=K(\mathbb{Z},3)$ and find that $2$-gerbes are principal $K(\mathbb{Z},3)$ bundles...

Comment: It might help to understand what it is you’re looking to do. A four form is just a map to a $K(Z,4)$, and that is fairly geometric. As John said, that’s the same as a $K(Z,3)$-bundle, which you can model as $E_8$ in reasonably low dimensions or use some other example of a $K(Z,3)$ with a group structure. I think you can even work directly with bundles of homotopy types in $\infty$-land. You could also model it as a differential cohomology class. Or you can look up the definition of a 2-gerbe in Breen’s work. I’m not sure any of these is better or worse than any of the others.

Comment: One requirement is that the model is geometric, i.e. does not involve objects which are only defined up to homotopy equivalence. Modeling a degree-$n$ cohomology class as a map to $K(Z,n)$ is not geometric, because $K(Z,n)$ is a homotopy type, not a concrete space. Similarly, modeling a degree-2 class as a map to $BU(1)$ is not geometric, because the classifying space of a group is defined only up to homotopy equivalence. A further more vague requirement is that I want a model which has a physics flavor. Roughly, it should involve Hilbert spaces in in some way.

Comment: @AntonKapustin in case you are still interested, I have a paper coming out soon that has a much easier geometric model than bundle 2-gerbes, as defined by Stevenson, and which suffices to capture all examples.

Comment: Sure, David, I would be happy to have a copy.

Answer (score 4):

One fairly concrete way to view these things is via the Cech model (= transition functions). But maybe this isn't what you were looking for...

Say the base space $X$ is a manifold or finite $CW$-complex. Choose a cover by contractible open sets $\amalg U_{i}\rightarrow X$.

A line bundle on $X$ is the data of functions $f_{ij}:U_{ij}\rightarrow U(1)$ on double overlaps, satisfying certain conditions on triple overlaps $U_{ijk}$.

A 1-gerble on $X$ is the data of line bundles $L_{ij}\rightarrow U_{ij}$ on double overlaps, isomorphisms $\phi_{ijk}:L_{ij}\otimes L_{jk}\rightarrow L_{ik}$ on triple overlaps, satisfying certain conditions on quadruple overlaps $U_{ijkl}$. Assuming the cover is nice enough, this is equivalent to functions $f_{ijk}:U_{ijk}\rightarrow U(1)$ satisfying conditions on $U_{ijkl}$.

So a 2-gerble would be either: assign a 1-gerble to each double overlap, as well as the appropriate coherence data on higher overlaps (which seems baffling to me), or: repeat the 1-gerbe recipe but start at triple overlaps, or: repeat the 0-gerbe recipe but start at quadruple overlaps.

Comment: I guess I should have made clear that I want a description which does not involve a choice of a cover.  The descriptions of 0-gerbes and 1-gerbes that I gave satisfy this requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Two possible ideas. One is that you can realize $K(\mathbb{Z},3)$ as the quotient $U(HS)/PU(\infty)$ where $U(HS)$ is the unitary group on the Hilbert space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators. However, I don’t know if you can see the group structure in this model to make a principal bundle. This construction is in

- Alan L. Carey, Diarmuid Crowley, Michael K. Murray, *Principal Bundles and the Dixmier Douady Class*, Commun.Math.Phys. **193** (1998) pp 171-196, doi:[10.1007/s002200050323](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002200050323), arXiv:[hep-th/9702147](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9702147).

There is also Andre Henriques’s conjecture that the outer automorphisms of a hyperfinite type III factor model $K(\mathbb{Z},3)$. See [`Naturally occuring'  $K(\pi, n)$ spaces, for $n \geq 2$.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44045/naturally-occuring-k-pi-n-spaces-for-n-geq-2)

Comment: The second option sounds good to me! I need to watch this lecture again (I already did once, years ago, but forgot most of it).

Answer (score 2):

*Bundle $n$-gerbes* seem to be what you are looking for.

Bundle gerbes *can* be defined w.r.t. an open cover (then it is what John Greenwood wrote), but don't have to. Instead of a cover, any surjective submersion is ok. $k$-fold intersections are then replaced by $k$-fold fibre products.

A nice example are *basic bundle gerbes* over compact Lie groups. For the groups $SU(n)$ and $Sp(n)$, one can construct them using an open cover of the Lie group, with a canonical line bundle over the double intersections. For the other simply-connected Lie groups, one needs to "resolve" the open sets by principal bundles over them, related to certain stabilizer subgroups. The union of their total space then gives a surjective submersion mapping to $G$, over whose 2-fold fibre product then again a canonical line bundle can be defined.

A further example are so-called *lifting bundle gerbes*, which are constructed from the problem of lifting the structure group of a principal bundle along a central extension. In this case, the surjective submersion is the bundle projection.

For bundle 2-gerbes, there is the *Chern-Simons bundle 2-gerbe*. Its surjective submersions is the bundle projection of a principal $G$-bundle. Over its 2-fold fibre product, it has a bundle gerbe, over its three-fold fibre product, a bundle gerbe isomorphism, over its 4-fold fibre product, a 2-isomorphism, and over its 5-fold fibre product, a condition. The Chern-Simons bundle 2-gerbe represents a class in $H^4(M,\mathbb{Z})$, the level of a Chern-Simons theory over $M$. It also carries a canonical connection, whose 3-holonomy is the value of the Chern-Simons theory on closed oriented 3-manifolds. This works for arbitrary Lie groups $G$, with no need to assume simply-connectedness.

Comment: I think bundle 2-gerbes will work for my purposes, thanks.